# How to use a Oozie job property in a Oozie workflow EL function?

Tags: el, oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator, bigdata

In my Oozie workflow, this is how a file is passed as a command line argument for a Java action:

```
<file>${concat(filesPath, 'config.properties')}</file>
```

While this works fine for a coordinator run, it has a problem when run manually through HUE [like in this video](http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-submit-any-oozie-jobs-directly-from/) -- 'filesPath' does not show up as a parameter in the dialog box that HUE throws up to take parameters.

I tried

```
 ${concat(${filesPath}, 'config.properties')}  and 
 ${concat(wf:conf(filesPath), 'config.properties')}
```

First throws syntax error and second returns/concats empty value.

I am basically looking for a way to declare a [parameter/job property](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.1_Workflow_Job_Properties_or_Parameters) in an Oozie Workflow EL function so that it works both for a Coordinator run and also for a manual run from HUE (should show a text box to enter value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
<file>${additionsPath}config.properties</file>
```

This would work only with the 'concat' EL function though.